# how do I disconnect a specific event

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a module script that looks something like this:

```
return {
  coolfunc = function(object)
    RunService.Stepped:Connect(function()
      print(object)
    end)
  end
}
```

and I call this script multiple times, how do I disconnect a specific connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Connect` method will return an connection object.

```
return {
  coolfunc = function(object)
    return RunService.Stepped:Connect(function()
      print(object)
    end)
  end
}
```

And you need store it somewhere.

```
connection = xxx.coolfunc(obj)
```

Then you can call the `Disconnect` method to disconnect the event.

```
if connection.Connected then
    connection:Disconnect()
end
```